# How to submit disable field in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to disable field.
But after submit form disable field is not submitting.

If it's not possible then how can I make field read only as well as can submit value.

Comment: Rather than using disabled you can use `readonly="readonly"` and can style it as per requirement

Comment: Please add any relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to use readonly attribute. But if you seek any other option, then you can use hidden fields.
On submit button click event, assign disable fields values to hidden fields and do form submit.
In server side you will be able to catch those hidden fields values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "readonly" attribute which may be "successful" in W3C parlance. 
A "disabled" attribute is NEVER successful. 
Only "successful" form elements are submitted with the form

Answer (score 0):

Use the `readonly` attribute instead.

```
$('selector').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Disabled form elements are not sent along a submit query.